# How can I automatically initialize mutable arrays/ dictionaries for my PFObject subclass? (Parse.com framework)

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have the following code in various parts of my app:

```
MyPFObjectSubclass *instance = [MyPFObjectSubclass object];
instance.myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
instance.myMutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary array];
```

I am *constantly* forgetting to initialize these types, and running into problems later when I attempt `setValue:forKey` or `addObject` methods.

It's a nice-to-have, I admit, but I would like to play it safe and roll these initializations into `+object` if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My PFObject subclasses all look roughly like this. I call [MyPFObject tlObject] to create a new instance.

```
@implementation MyPFObject 

@dynamic objectUUID;
// Other fields
+ (MyPFObject*) tlObject
{
    MyPFObject* obj = [self object];
    [obj tlObjectInit];
    // Other initializations
    return obj;
}

+ (NSString*) parseClassName
{
    return @"MyPFObject";
}

+ (PFQuery*) query
{
    PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName: [self parseClassName]];
    // Add includeKeys here
    return query;
}

@end
```

I have a category on PFObject that includes tlObjectInit. The field objectUUID is there so that I have a value that can uniquely identify the object BEFORE IT IS SAVED. This is necessary because I sometimes create sets of objects that refer to one another. The Parse objectID is not set until it is saved.

```
@implementation PFObject (TL)
- (void) tlObjectInit
{
    NSString* format = [[self parseClassName] stringByAppendingString: @"-%@"];
    [self setObject: [NSUUID uuidStringInFormat: format]
             forKey: @"objectUUID"];
}
// Add other initializations here
@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks pretty good, I think I'll use this.

Comment: Although I'm not clear on how the `stringByAppendingString:@-%@"` bit works. What is that code doing? Does it guarantee you a unique objectId in the right format?

Comment: That creates a format string that is "<class name>-%@". The next line produces a UUID prepended by the class name. I do this with all my UUIDs so that when I see the UUID in isolation I know what it identifies.

Comment: I'd love an answer to this same question, but the accepted answer is not an answer to the original question.

Comment: Not sure why you say that. You put your array inits where it says "Other Initializations". Or are you saying you really want to call [MyPFObject object] and not [MyPFObject tlObject]?

Answer (score 0):

In your `MyPFObjectSubclass`, override the init method:

```
-(instancetype) init
{
  if (self = [super init])
    {
       _myMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
       _myMutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    }
  return self;
}
```

I guess your `object` method call one way or the other the init method.

Edit:
It looks like you use the Parse framework. As told in the reference, the `PFObject` `init` method shouldn't be overridden by subclasses.

Comment: Tried this, but I get `NSInternalInconsistencyException, reason: The init method of MyPFObjectSubclass set values on the object, which is not allowed.'`

Comment: Do you have any informations to give about your MyPFObjectSubclass class? I guess its a subclass of MyPFObject, but MyPFObject inherits from which class?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say, `MyPFObjectSubclass` is a subclass of `PFObject`

Comment: It looks like you're using the Parse framework. Then you may want to read the PFObject class reference about subclassing. It explicitly say to not override the init method. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Ah yes - I tagged it parse.com but I should have made it more explicit